# Too many arguments on Slider (wxPython)

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am using wxPython on Python 2.7, and I am trying to add a slider using a Youtube tutorial of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5sxImX3gog.
However, I keep getting an error message stating too many arguments. The error code is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\ActionFrame.py", line 15, in <module>
frame=ActionFrame(parent=None,id=-1)
File "C:\Python27\ActionFrame.py", line 10, in __init__
slider.SetTickFreq(5,1)
TypeError: Slider.SetTickFreq(): too many arguments
```

The code I am using is below.

```
import wx

class ActionFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        locale = wx.Locale(wx.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Frame", size=(300,200))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        slider=wx.Slider(panel, -1, 50, 1, 100, pos=(10,10), size=(250, -1), style=wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS)
        slider.SetTickFreq(5,1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    frame=ActionFrame(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
   app.MainLoop()
```

What am I doing wrong?? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `SetTickFreq` only takes one integer, not two.  Documentation link: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Slider.html#wx.Slider.SetTickFreq

Comment: Got it working! Thank you.